# How to make an Android Translucent theme a little darker?

Tags: android

I use following Android theme in my Android manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

It's a translucent theme, and it has a translucent background, but I need to make the background of this theme a small darker, or replace the one to another (with translucent background, but it should be a little darker). Please, tell me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Or if you want the background to be transparent, use the Translucent theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

If you like a theme, but want to tweak it, just add the theme as the parent of your custom theme. For example, you can modify the traditional light theme to use your own color like this:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

(Note that the color needs to supplied as a separate resource here because the android:windowBackground attribute only supports a reference to another resource; unlike android:colorBackground, it can not be given a color literal.)

Now use CustomTheme instead of Theme.Light inside the Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to change transparency of background, not a color. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way is to define it as a drawable in which the drawable is the right transparent gray you are looking for. You can do this in many applications such as photoshop.

Comment: Colors in Android are 4 byte #ff001122 the first byte beeing the alpha channel (transparency)

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem: i wanted to create an activity with small size (than the size of device screen) and custom color and make the background darker

I suggest you to edit the theme of activity in Android manifest file as following :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

I hope this will help you