# force close when change theme in android manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, themes

I have changed the theme for some activities, but when I want to run the AVD go to Force Stop.
This is my activity manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.gpsportalsms.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent."
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
```

and this is my xml activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gpsportalsms.LoginActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


</FrameLayout>
```

I add the LogCat in below:

```
 06-29 16:10:24.015: W/dalvikvm(1420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0xa4ceeb20)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): Process: com.example.gpsportalsms, PID: 1420
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpsportalsms/com.example.gpsportalsms.NotifySMSReceived}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
  06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
  06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at com.example.gpsportalsms.NotifySMSReceived.onCreate(NotifySMSReceived.java:20)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420):    ... 11 more
```

What is wrong?

Comment: please post your Logcat..

Comment: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent."` looks quite culprit. Make sure it's right.

Comment: Remove the '**.**' in `Translucent.`, and give off a try.

Comment: I removed the ".". but i have this problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "." in Theme.Translucent.

Use this

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.example.gpsportalsms.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
```

Comment: this is in my logCat: 
 06-29 16:10:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpsportalsms/com.example.gpsportalsms.NotifySMSReceived}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search lands me into this SO question : [How to make an Android Translucent theme a little darker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756619/how-to-make-an-android-translucent-theme-a-little-darker)

The mentioned question however isn't much related to yours, but provides some reference. Haven't tried though.

As it says the code must be like

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.gpsportalsms.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
```

Notice the '**.**' shouldn't be there.